# Is there an adjective meaning "punished unfairly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am not looking for innocent. Innocent describes that they are not the one who did it, rather I am looking for how they are innocent, but punished for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also consider "wrongfully." It's an adverb, not an adjective, but seems more specific than "unfairly." Here's the definition from the online Oxford Dictionaries:

> In an unfair, unjust, or illegal manner:
>
> He was wrongfully convicted of murder.
>
> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wrongfully

Another possibility is "railroaded" a verb, defined here by Dictionary.com as:

> Informal. to convict (a person) in a hasty manner by means of false charges or insufficient evidence:
>   The prisoner insisted he had been railroaded.
>
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/railroaded

Answer (score 2):

The word "scapegoat" comes to mind. Also "patsy" or "fall guy". But all of these describe a person who is set up by others to be unfairly punished.  I was once punished for a crime I did not commit, but that was just incompetent police work, so none of the terms I've given would apply to me in that context. For that situation, I can't think of anything more specific than "victim"; which I perceive is more general than what you're looking for.

Comment: Scapegoat could work.

Comment: @Drew I thought my answer made that point. Is it not evident in the paragraph I wrote?